# Craft 3 dashboard error

Tags: craft3, dashboard

Having successfully installed Craft 3 via composer – all seems fine but on each load of the admin dashboard I get a notice on red bg: 
'An unknown error occurred' need I worry about this? couldn't see anything obvious in the logs – all else seems fine – using php 7.0.0 / Mamp Pro and used the line below when setting up:

```
PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin:$PATH"
```

Or is a fresh install required?

Comment: If you look in your `craft/storage/logs` files and search for `[error]`, you should see what the underlying message is that's causing the "unknown error occurred" message to flash.

Comment: Thanks, I can see

`FROM deprecationerrors 
2018-02-21 14:26:19 [::1][1][-][profile begin][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT COUNT(`id`)
FROM `deprecationerrors`
2018-02-21 14:26:19 [::1][1][-][profile end][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT COUNT(`id`)
FROM `deprecationerrors`
2018-02-21 14:26:19 [::1][1][-][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'admin/actions/app/get-utilities-badge-count'' `

Comment: but not sure what this actually means is wrong?

Comment: and also this:

[::1][1][-][info][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT `id`, `description`, `progress`, `timeUpdated`, `fail`, `error`

assuming some kind of db issue?

Comment: Those are just informational.  Did you search for `[error]` with the square brackets and everything?

Comment: Thanks, I see:

[::1][1][-][error][GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to craftcms.com:443  (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /Users/kev/Documents/WEBSITES/DEV/craft3/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186 

in that search

Comment: That's the one! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running MAMP (and even if you're not, but it's common you are) and you're getting this error when connecting to Craft's web services:

> cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to craftcms.com:443

Then you're running an older version of MAMP and you need to upgrade to the latest.

The older versions are trying to connect over https using an older SSL protocol (TLS 1.0) that is no longer supported.

Comment: Once Mamp Pro 4 installed that did indeed remove the alert, thanks again :)